# Javascript for loop and calender

Tags: javascript, for-loop, calendar

This is supposed to be a calender of December, and to have a button that will change the week of the current day to have a new/different background color. Right now, im trying to do it so in a for loop, find class name of the variable in the array that matches the current date/meets all conditions, and then set a style for that class name using Javascript, so that now the whole class will have a different background color..

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>December Calender</h1>
        <button onclick="snow()">demo</button>

    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th class="demo" >sun</th>
            <th class="demo2">mon</th>
            <th class="demo2">tue</th>
            <th class="demo2" >wed</th>
            <th class="demo2">thu</th>
            <th class="demo2">fri</th>
            <th class="demo2">sat</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="demo2" class="one">1</td>
            <td class="demo2" class="one">2</td>
            <td class="demo2" class="one">3</td>
            <td class="demo2" class="one">4</td>
            <td class="demo2" class="one">5</td>
            <td class="demo2" class="one">6</td>
            <td class="demo2" class="one">7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="demo3" class="two">8</td>
            <td class="demo3" class="two">9</td>
            <td class="demo3" class="two">10</td>
            <td class="demo3" class="two">11</td>
            <td class="demo3" class="two">12</td>
            <td class="demo3" class="two">13</td>
            <td class="demo2" class="two">14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="demo2" class="three">15</td>
            <td class="demo2" class="three">16</td>
            <td class="demo2" class="three">17</td>
            <td class="demo2" class="three">18</td>
            <td class="demo2" class="three">19</td>
            <td class="demo2" class="three">20</td>
            <td class="demo2" class="three">21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="demo3" class="four">22</td>
            <td class="demo3" class="four">23</td>
            <td class="demo3" class="four">24</td>
            <td class="demo3" class="four">25</td>
            <td class="demo3" class="four">26</td>
            <td class="demo3" class="four">27</td>
            <td class="demo2" class="four">28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="demo3" class="five">29</td>
            <td class="demo3" class="five">30</td>
            <td class="demo3" class="five">31</td>
            <td class="demo3" class="five"></td>
            <td class="demo3" class="five"></td>
            <td class="demo3" class="five"></td>
            <td class="demo2" class="five"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>

        function snow() {
        let date = new Date();


        let inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].innerHTML == date.getDate()) {

            }
        }
        }

    </script>


</body>

</html>```
````

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the [<time>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time) element for this?

Comment: need to do in js.

Comment: you can. you can just get the list of `time` elements instead of `td` elements. <time> elements however are *meant* to save datetime information in their attributes and so are much easier to convert to `Date` objects. You should be including those to accurately get the date instead of converting it from whatever happens to be in innerText.

Answer (score 0):

`inputs[i].classList` should give you a string containing all the classes of the element.

Answer (score 0):

As Oscar Q. mentions, you can read and write css classes through the classList object.

Additionally you can run Array methods on HTMLCollections (including `forAll` and `filter`) using `call`.

Combining the two looks something like this:

```js
let date = new Date(Date.now());

let inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
let matches = Array.prototype.filter.call(inputs, element => {
   return (parseInt(element.innerText) === date.getDate());
});

for(let match of matches) {
    match.classList.add("today");
}
```